# How to know when pdfFindController.executeCommand has executed

Tags: pdf.js

I am building a webapp with Angular 7 and I try to implement search functionality like in https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html.

I have it working, but I like to show current match and total matches like in the official viewer. My code looks like this:

```
this.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', this.searchCommand);
let { current, total, } = this.pdfFindController._requestMatchesCount();
this.currentMatch = current;
this.numberOfSearchMatches = total;
console.log('Number of matches', this.currentMatch, '/', 
this.numberOfSearchMatches);
```

When I run this code this.currentMatch is showing the previous match instead of the current match. If I modify the code like this:

```
this.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', this.searchCommand);
setTimeout(() => {    
let { current, total, } = 
    this.pdfFindController._requestMatchesCount();
    this.currentMatch = current;
    this.numberOfSearchMatches = total;
    console.log('Number of matches', this.currentMatch, '/', 
    this.numberOfSearchMatches);
}, 1000);
```

then this.currentMatch contains the correct match number. So I guess I need to wait for something between calling executeCommand and _requestMatcheCount. I have searched the code extensively, but I have not found a way to know when executeCommand has finished so _requestMatchesCount can be safely called. Can anybody tell me how I can know that executeCommand has finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we are, maybe a little late!

`this.pdfComponent.pdfViewer.eventBus.on('updatefindmatchescount', data => {
    this.searchMatchesLength = data.matchesCount.total;
});`

Comment: Hey alberto is there any possibilities that i can get a callback if there are no matches found??

Comment: The event `updatefindmatchescount` is fired for all pages that contain the search term. How do I know whether the search finished for _all_ the pages? If a search finds something on page 5 of 1000, then the state changes to `FOUND`. However the search might take some more seconds and there is no state for 'search finished'.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to know if there isn't any results from searching on pdf only you have to check the states. You can also check on event 'updatefindcontrolstate'.
The states are the following:

```
const FindState = {
   FOUND: 0,
   NOT_FOUND: 1,
   WRAPPED: 2,
   PENDING: 3
};
```

So if you check the state with value for NOT_FOUND(1) then you will be able to know if no results found after search.

```
this.pdfComponent.pdfViewer.eventBus.on('updatefindcontrolstate', data => {
    if (data.state === FindState.NOT_FOUND) {
         // you have no results here
    }
});
```